# AJAX con PHP y Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hola estoy intentando implementar *Jquery* en mi aplicación para lo cual lo que quiero hacer es en base a un *combobox* rellenar los *option* de otro *combobox*, en mi aplicacion utilizo *HTML* con *PHP* y *Codeigniter* como framework.

Esta es la estructura de la base de datos que estoy utilizando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De la cual en base a la *especialidad_perito* quiero traer *mencion_perito* hasta ahora cargo los datos de mencion en el combo box y comprobe que jquery esta funcionando en mi pagina ya que agregue un alert para eso.

esta es mi vista:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()?>peritos/peritosC/consultarPeritos" name="buscar">
        <td>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Selecciona Peritaje : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="category" id="category" required>
                        <option value="">SELECCIONE UNA ESPECIALIDAD PERITO</option>
                        <?php foreach($category as $row):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row->especialidad_perito;?>"><?php echo $row->especialidad_perito;?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>
            </td>
            <br>
            <td><label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label">Selecciona Mención : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="sub_category" name="sub_category" required>
                        <option>No Selected</option>

            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#category').change(function(){ 
                var especialidad_perito=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "<?php echo site_url('peritosC/get_sub_category');?>",
                    method : "POST",
                    data : {especialidad_perito: especialidad_perito},
                    async : true,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success: function(data){

                        var html = '';
                        var i;
                        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            html += '<option value='+data[i].mencion_perito+'>'+data[i].mencion_perito+'</option>';
                        }
                        $('#sub_category').html(html);

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }); 

        });
    </script>
            </div>
            </td>
    </td>
      <td>  
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-success mr-2">BUSCAR</button> </td>
                   </tr>
             </form>


    </table>
```

mi controlador:
class peritosC extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('peritos/peritosM');
}

function index(){
    $this->load->model('peritosM');
    $data['category'] = $this->peritosM->get_peritos()->result();
    $this->load->view('peritos/listadoPeritos', $data);
}

function get_sub_category(){
    $this->load->model('peritosM');
    $category_id = $this->input->post('especialidad_perito',TRUE);
    $data = $this->peritosM->get_sub_category($category_id)->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

y mi modelo: class peritosM extends CI_Model{

```
function get_peritos(){
    $query = $this->db->group_by('especialidad_perito');
    $query = $this->db->get('saus_peritos');
    return $query;  
}

function get_sub_category($especialidad_perito){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mencion_perito', array('mencion_perito' => $especialidad_perito));
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ya validaste que te esta retornando datos al momento de hacer el `change` solo debes recorrer esa data y usar un `.append()`

```
 $('#category').change(function(){ 
                var especialidad_perito=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "<?php echo site_url('peritosC/get_sub_category');?>",
                    method : "POST",
                    data : {especialidad_perito: especialidad_perito},
                    async : true,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success: function(data){

                        var i;
                        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            $('#sub_category').append('<option value='+data[i].mencion_perito+'>'+data[i].mencion_perito+'</option>');
                        }


                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: hola como puedo validar que retornan datos?

Comment: haciendo un console.log(data)

Comment: agregue el console.log(data) pero no me muestra nada, lo agregue en el success y agure un else en caso contrario pero no muestra nada en ningún caso.

Comment: ahh entonces puede ser que la consulta no te esta arrojando nada porque creeme que ese codigo te funciona porque te funciona, empieza a imprimir a varibale tanto en el php como en el javascript para ver los datos que llegan y las respuestas que obtienes para despues moler eso en la vista